# Android - where is com.google.android.dialer in the file system

Tags: android, shell, adb, native, android-dialer

I have an Android phone with com.google.android.dialer application to dial a number ( I get the name by executing `ps` command after `adb shell`). But I don't succeed to know where is the application.

ls, ps, cat and so can be found in /system/bin but where is com.google.android.dialer ? I didn't find it in /data/app.

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you want read its source code? Or trigger it in some way?

Answer (score 1):

System app's apk's are in `/system/app`.

System app's data is in `/system/data`.

User app's apk's are in `/data/app`.

User app's data is in `/data/data`.

Comment: I looked in these directories and some others (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed) but nothing. Maybe I don't understand something. I have subdirectory in /system/app and maybe com.google.android.dialer is in apk but how `am start com.google.android.dialer` know what is the good path?

Comment: I can't look in your system, you should find it yourself. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is to dial a number, for that you can use:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:111-1111-1111
```

Comment: it is not exactly what i was looking for but your answer is still interesting.

Answer (score 0):

com.google.android.dialer is in /system/priv-app/Dialer

I guess `am` is looking in all directories containing applications (/system/priv-app,/system/app ...) but I'm sure about that.